# showing total population changes and sorting by the last time pop was changed

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get create a table using the data i have in my database and using php code that will look at pop of each town and add them all up to get the told pop for each day and then takes the told pop and finds when the last time the pop has been changed and outputs that data and sort by the last time there was a pop change. Any help would be great

**What it shows right now**

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| Last_time_pop_changed  | Player_name   |total_population_change|
+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| 2016-02-07 00:03:46    | .Mjölnir.     |                 383846|
| 2016-02-08 00:03:25    | .Mjölnir.     |                 384309|
| 2016-02-09 00:03:30    | .Mjölnir.     |                 384347|
| 2016-02-10 00:04:09    | .Mjölnir.     |                 384374|
| 2016-02-11 00:03:29    | .Mjölnir.     |                 385163|
| 2016-02-12 00:02:51    | .Mjölnir.     |                 385173|
| 2016-02-13 00:02:59    | .Mjölnir.     |                 385190|
| 2016-02-14 00:03:12    | .Mjölnir.     |                 385904|
| 2016-02-15 00:04:11    | .Mjölnir.     |                 386217|
| 2016-02-16 00:03:58    | .Mjölnir.     |                 386254|
| 2016-02-17 00:03:39    | .Mjölnir.     |                 386295|
| 2016-02-07 00:03:46    |  Rebellions   |                  23084|
| 2016-02-08 00:03:25    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-09 00:03:30    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-10 00:04:09    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-11 00:03:29    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-12 00:02:51    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-13 00:02:59    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-14 00:03:12    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-15 00:04:11    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-16 00:03:58    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|
| 2016-02-17 00:03:39    |  Rebellions   |                  22382|   
+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

**What i would like it to show**

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| Last_time_pop_changed  | Player_name   |total_population_change|
+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| 2016-02-08 00:03:25    |  Rebellions   |                   -702|
| 2016-02-16 00:03:58    | .Mjölnir.     |                     41|
+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------------------+
```

**PHP code**

```
$sql="SELECT players.*, town_deltas.*, town_deltas.town_id, sum( town_deltas.population ) as total_population  FROM `town_deltas` LEFT JOIN players ON town_deltas.owner_id = players.player_id  GROUP BY owner_id, data_timestamp ORDER BY `town_deltas`.`town_id` ASC, `town_deltas`.`data_timestamp` ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "<table>
<tr>

<th>Last_time_pop_changed</th>

<th>Player_name</th>


<td>total_population_change</td>

</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr>";


echo "<td>" . $row['data_timestamp'] . "</td>";

echo "<td>" . $row['Player_name'] . "</td>";


echo "<td>" . $row['total_population'] . "</td>";


echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Town Deltas**

```
                primary_key :id
                DateTime :happened_at
                Integer :town_id, :index => true
                Integer :owner_id, :index => true
                String :name, :index => true
                Integer :population
                TrueClass :is_capital
                TrueClass :is_alliance_capital
```

**Player table**

```
            Integer :player_id, :primary_key => true
            foreign_key :race_id, :races
            Integer :alliance_id, :null => true
            Integer :alliance_role_id, :null => true
            String :Player_name, :index => true
```

Comment: is `owner_id` and `data_timestamp` columns of table `town_details`?

Comment: Yes they are part of the town_deltas table

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provide the table structure of both tables (`town_details` and `players`)

Comment: ok I will go pull the  table structure  and put them in the Question

Comment: Also can you explain how you come up with `-702` and `41` in `total_population_change` ?

Comment: To get the -702 I took Rebellions  Told pop  from 2016-02-08  and minus   Rebellions  Told pop from  2016-02-08 since that was the last time there was a pop change. I did the same for the 41 but used .Mjölnir. last up change  I have also added the code i used to create the tables (used ruby code)

Comment: still dont understand where those numbers are coming from you say _"took Rebellions Told pop from 2016-02-08 and minus Rebellions Told pop from 2016-02-08 "_ but that doesnt really tell me anything. Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: The game i am playing a web game that has xml files that are updated everyday these xml files are full of data about towns/players/alliance/etc. I have code that takes xml files and puts it into my database (mySQL). The PHP code i have right now takes all a player's towns and add them all together for change data. What i want to do is to create a table that uses the data from the database and give a list of every player and when the last time they had built something. Rebellions  is an inactive player who hasnt played for many weeks.

Comment: I am sry i am not explaining very well     http://illyriad.bestmagicbears.com/gettown.php?q=239180  <---- show is a table of every town that Rebellions has                                                                                  http://illyriad.bestmagicbears.com/gettown2.php?q=239180  <---- show the told pop for each day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can think of is to loop over the names one at a time with

```
    select data_timestamp,sum(total_population_change) from (select * from town_deltas where Player_name  = name limit 2) as t;
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since total_population_change isn't defined

Comment: argh! I was testing with sum forgot to finish the process. I found some examples with a sequence field, but it's slightly different.